# My programm is crashes when i compile std::cout using Clang on Windows 10

Tags: gcc, g++, clang, llvm, clang++

My app crashes when I compile `std::cout` using Clang on Windows 10. Clang compile this without warnings or errors. Same problem with mingw-64.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    std::cout << "Some text\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

With mingw-64 problem solved by passing `-static` parameter to g++ compiler.

Issue probably with some missed library that is using to output text in command line. I can't compile  my apps every time using this param, because such a simple bunch of code takes up 2.5**MB** of memory in executable.

Upd: `printf()` works fine.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: no error message)) app just crash without any error message... any code below cout wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem. It was because PATH had path to broken libstdc++.dll.